# Trying to understand compilation failure surrounding traits

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, traits, type-level-computation

I'm trying to do some type level programming using traits, and bumped into an edge case where the compiler infinitely expands a type while trying to prove a constraint, while I expect it to converge instead.

This error is also unstable, as minor changes that I would not expect to make a difference suddenly cause the program to compile successfully.

I am struggling to understand what's special about the first program that makes the compiler go crazy. Is it missing some kind of constraint?

#### Original program with error

Here is the original program. This has been heavily reduced to reproduce the error. The original was actually generated by a macro from an experimental type level programming crate called `typ`.

```rust
// Just setting up some simple type level lists.
pub struct HCons<H, T> {
    pub head: H,
    pub tail: T,
}
pub struct HNil;

pub trait HList {}
impl HList for HNil {}
impl<H, T: HList> HList for HCons<H, T> {}


// Trait-encoded type level function that maps over these lists
pub trait MapList<L> {
    type Output;
}
impl MapList<HNil> for () {
    type Output = HNil;
}
impl<X, T: HList> MapList<HCons<X, T>> for () where (): DoMapList<T> {
    type Output = HCons<X, <() as DoMapList<T>>::Output>;
}


// Trait-encoded type level function that calls the other function
pub trait DoMapList<L: HList> where Self::Output: HList {
    type Output;
}

impl<L: HList> DoMapList<L> for () where
    (): MapList<L>,
    <() as MapList<L>>::Output: HList
{
    type Output = <() as MapList<L>>::Output;
}


// Helper type
type DoMapListOp<L> = <() as DoMapList<L>>::Output;



pub struct Intermediate<A: HList> where (): DoMapList<A> {
    pub foo: DoMapListOp<A>,
}

pub trait Tester<A: HList> where (): DoMapList<A> {
    fn foo() -> Intermediate<A>;
}

struct Bar;

impl Tester<HCons<i32, HNil>> for Bar {
    fn foo() -> Intermediate<HCons<i32, HNil>> {
        return Intermediate { foo: HCons { head: 5, tail: HNil {} } }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `(): DoMapList<_>`
  --> <source>:55:16
   |
55 |         return Intermediate { foo: HCons { head: 5, tail: HNil {} } }
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider increasing the recursion limit by adding a `#![recursion_limit = "256"]` attribute to your crate (`example`)
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `MapList<HCons<_, _>>` for `()`
  --> <source>:20:19
   |
20 | impl<X, T: HList> MapList<HCons<X, T>> for () where (): DoMapList<T> {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `DoMapList<HCons<_, _>>` for `()`
  --> <source>:30:16
   |
30 | impl<L: HList> DoMapList<L> for () where
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^
   = note: 126 redundant requirements hidden
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `DoMapList<HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, HCons<_, _>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>` for `()`
note: required by a bound in `Intermediate`
  --> <source>:43:45
   |
43 | pub struct Intermediate<A: HList> where (): DoMapList<A> {
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Intermediate`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0275`.
Compiler returned: 1
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vve1jeM9x)

#### `Intermediate` newtype removed, compiles

Here is a version where I removed the `Intermediate` newtype. This for some reason builds successfully.

```rust
// Just setting up some simple type level lists.
pub struct HCons<H, T> {
    pub head: H,
    pub tail: T,
}
pub struct HNil;

pub trait HList {}
impl HList for HNil {}
impl<H, T: HList> HList for HCons<H, T> {}


// Trait-encoded type level function that maps over these lists
pub trait MapList<L> {
    type Output;
}
impl MapList<HNil> for () {
    type Output = HNil;
}
impl<X, T: HList> MapList<HCons<X, T>> for () where (): DoMapList<T> {
    type Output = HCons<X, <() as DoMapList<T>>::Output>;
}


// Trait-encoded type level function that calls the other function
pub trait DoMapList<L: HList> where Self::Output: HList {
    type Output;
}

impl<L: HList> DoMapList<L> for () where
    (): MapList<L>,
    <() as MapList<L>>::Output: HList
{
    type Output = <() as MapList<L>>::Output;
}


// Helper type
type DoMapListOp<L> = <() as DoMapList<L>>::Output;



pub trait Tester<A: HList> where (): DoMapList<A> {
    fn foo() -> DoMapListOp<A>;
}

struct Bar;

impl Tester<HCons<i32, HNil>> for Bar {
    fn foo() -> DoMapListOp<HCons<i32, HNil>> {
        return HCons { head: 5, tail: HNil {} }
    }
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/85hPaser7)

#### `DoMapList` trait removed, compiles

Next is a version where I removed the intermediate `DoMapList` trait. This also builds successfully.

```rust
// Just setting up some simple type level lists.
pub struct HCons<H, T> {
    pub head: H,
    pub tail: T,
}
pub struct HNil;

pub trait HList {}
impl HList for HNil {}
impl<H, T: HList> HList for HCons<H, T> {}


// Trait-encoded type level function that maps over these lists
pub trait MapList<L> {
    type Output;
}
impl MapList<HNil> for () {
    type Output = HNil;
}
impl<X, T: HList> MapList<HCons<X, T>> for () where (): MapList<T> {
    type Output = HCons<X, <() as MapList<T>>::Output>;
}


// Helper type
type DoMapListOp<L> = <() as MapList<L>>::Output;



pub struct Intermediate<A: HList> where (): MapList<A> {
    pub foo: DoMapListOp<A>,
}

pub trait Tester<A: HList> where (): MapList<A> {
    fn foo() -> Intermediate<A>;
}

struct Bar;

impl Tester<HCons<i32, HNil>> for Bar {
    fn foo() -> Intermediate<HCons<i32, HNil>> {
        return Intermediate { foo: HCons { head: 5, tail: HNil {} } }
    }
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7M1vKreqT)

#### `MapList` trait calls itself, compiles

Lastly I have a version where I do keep the `DoMapList` trait, but make the `MapList` trait directly call itself. This also builds successfully.

```rust
// Just setting up some simple type level lists.
pub struct HCons<H, T> {
    pub head: H,
    pub tail: T,
}
pub struct HNil;

pub trait HList {}
impl HList for HNil {}
impl<H, T: HList> HList for HCons<H, T> {}


// Trait-encoded type level function that maps over these lists
pub trait MapList<L> {
    type Output;
}
impl MapList<HNil> for () {
    type Output = HNil;
}
impl<X, T: HList> MapList<HCons<X, T>> for () where (): MapList<T> {
    type Output = HCons<X, <() as MapList<T>>::Output>;
}


// Trait-encoded type level function that calls the other function
pub trait DoMapList<L: HList> where Self::Output: HList {
    type Output;
}

impl<L: HList> DoMapList<L> for () where
    (): MapList<L>,
    <() as MapList<L>>::Output: HList
{
    type Output = <() as MapList<L>>::Output;
}


// Helper type
type DoMapListOp<L> = <() as DoMapList<L>>::Output;



pub struct Intermediate<A: HList> where (): DoMapList<A> {
    pub foo: DoMapListOp<A>,
}

pub trait Tester<A: HList> where (): DoMapList<A> {
    fn foo() -> Intermediate<A>;
}

struct Bar;

impl Tester<HCons<i32, HNil>> for Bar {
    fn foo() -> Intermediate<HCons<i32, HNil>> {
        return Intermediate { foo: HCons { head: 5, tail: HNil {} } }
    }
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z56f3369T)

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the Rust Programming discord told me it is a bug in the trait system.